# Are atomic transactions in django on database level?

Tags: django, database, atomic

I have a django backend application that I'm running on a docker container, 
I'm using atomic transactions at some places where it's needed

So because I have high traffic and there are many places that require expensive computations, I wanted to run another instance of the django application, and balance the load,

My question is given `instance1` started an atomic transaction, and `instance2` want to start an atomic transaction on the same record, does `instance2` sees that `instance1` is running an atomic transaction so the request will wait till `instance1` is finished?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Django is capable to handle those kind of request!

For concurrent transactions you can use `select_for_update` method on `manager` or `queryset` object inside `transaction.atomic()` block. you can find documentation on `select_for_update` from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update).

> **Note**: Usage of `transaction.atomic()` with select_for_update() is used to handle concurrency and atomicity on database level.

`select_for_update` executes following type of query on database level.

```
SELECT FOR UPDATE wallet where wallet.id = '1'
```

for i.e

```
from django.db import transaction

user_wallet = Wallet.objects.select_for_update().get(user=request.user)  # select for update query
with transaction.atomic():   # atomic transactions block
    user_wallet.amount += Decimal('200')  # updating user's wallet amount
    user_wallet.save()
```

For more information refer to [Django Database Transactions documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/transactions/)